# 2 Questions on : Make your solutions available in Microsoft AppSource and within Office

Tags: office-addins, office-store

store team,

we are trying to publish our Excel addin and have some questions on how to proceed on two topics.

**Question 1:** information for testing [**100.14.1  Testing Instructions:**] the addin is not relying on a service and delivers all functions without a service. You can buy an additional service, which is shown in the addin, to store certain data into a SQL server but that is not mandatory for the addin to work and cannot be conducted in-app. Where/how can we describe this behaviour so that this won't be a failure/critical validation?

**Question 2:** we want to exclude Excel 2013 [1100.4.4.1  Office 2013 ] to work with our addin. how can we achieve that?

Best Regards,

tbr

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: If there is any functionality mentioned in the description, it is expected to be inside the add-in. If there is functionality that requires a paid/premium account, you should provide a test account in the certification notes field in Partner Center when resubmitting.
Answer 2: Office 2013 is a supported platform in validation and as such the add-in is expected to be functional there. Please see the following link to the page that lists all of the API's and the platforms that support them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-in-availability#excel

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, still an open issue regarding Q/A 2.


Office 2013 does not, for example, offer any ExcelAPI to access the Worksheet. Do you have a Workaround for alle missing ExcelAPI features that are necessary for users of newer Versions?

What should we do for functions that are not supported in Office 2013?!

Best Regards,

tbr

Comment: If that platform does not support certain features/ functionalities, is it an option to not include them on that Platform whilst still including the core functionality of the add-in.

Comment: Thanks again.

How can we correctly require the ExcelAPI in the Office AddIn manifest?
According to the XML Schema found in the online docs at [link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-owemxml/00e4ee5d-2eb8-47f2-9008-8beb6ff45189) , the correct form would be:
`code`<Requirements> <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1"> <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.1"/> </Sets> </Requirements> `code`

...as the direct child of <OfficeApp>”.
When we do this, the error says: “The element 'OfficeApp' has invalid child element 'Requirements'”.

What can we do?